# How to serialize a self-defined class containing a STL container of another self-defined class using boost serialization easily?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, stl

I have read the tutorial here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html and googled a lot of pages, but I am still not sure how to do it.

I have read how to serialize a self-defined class and how to serialize a self-defined class containing STL container of std::string or pointers. But I'm not sure how to serialize a self-defined class containing a STL container of another self-defined class using boost serialization easily? Since std::string and pointers are standard C++ types, the boost knows how to deal with them. In case of a STL container of self-defined class, I fell I have to tell boost how to deal with it when serializing. But how? This is my self-defined 2 classes.

```
class Instance
{
public:
    Instance(){}
    ~Instance();
    //... a lot of functions here.
private:
    InstanceIdentity identity_;
    mutable ClassLabel class_label_;
    mutable FeatureGroup features_;
    friend class InstanceManager;
};

class InstanceManager
{
public:
    InstanceManager(){}
    ~InstanceManager();
    // a lot of functions here.
private:
    set<Instance> instances_;
};
```

According to the tutorial part of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html , since boost knows how to deal with STL container, so what I need to do is add

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & instances_;
}
```

in class InstanceManager. And add

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // A lot of things like the following example.
    //ar & degrees;
    //ar & minutes;
    //ar & seconds;
}
```

in class Instance. Is that right? Or there is better ways. It takes much time to test this by coding. So, can anyone tell me the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Here's a complete working example. I invented some simple types:

```
struct InstanceIdentity { int id;            };
struct ClassLabel       { std::string value; };
struct FeatureGroup     { size_t count;      };
```

With non-intrusive serialization:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, InstanceIdentity& ii, unsigned) { ar & ii.id; }
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, ClassLabel& cl, unsigned) { ar & cl.value; }
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, FeatureGroup& fg, unsigned) { ar & fg.count; }
} }
```

The `Instance` and `InstanceManager` classes have their serialize-methods as a member (due the the private members):

```
template <typename Ar>
    void Instance::serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & identity_ & class_label_ & features_; }

template <typename Ar>
    void InstanceManager::serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & instances_; }
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfffffd73f93b69f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

struct InstanceIdentity { int id;            };
struct ClassLabel       { std::string value; };
struct FeatureGroup     { size_t count;      };

class Instance
{
public:
    Instance(){}
    ~Instance() = default;
    //... a lot of functions here.

    bool operator<(Instance const& other) const {
        return identity_.id < other.identity_.id;
    }
private:
    InstanceIdentity identity_;
    mutable ClassLabel class_label_;
    mutable FeatureGroup features_;
    friend class InstanceManager;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & identity_ & class_label_ & features_; }
};

class InstanceManager
{
public:
    InstanceManager()
    {
        Instance a, b, c;

        a.class_label_.value = "label a";
        b.class_label_.value = "label b";
        c.class_label_.value = "label c";

        a.features_.count = 42;
        b.features_.count = 24;
        c.features_.count = -9;

        a.identity_.id = rand();
        b.identity_.id = rand();
        c.identity_.id = rand();

        instances_.insert(instances_.end(), a);
        instances_.insert(instances_.end(), b);
        instances_.insert(instances_.end(), c);
    }

    ~InstanceManager() = default;
    // a lot of functions here.
private:
    std::set<Instance> instances_;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & instances_; }
};

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, InstanceIdentity& ii, unsigned) { ar & ii.id; }
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, ClassLabel& cl, unsigned) { ar & cl.value; }
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, FeatureGroup& fg, unsigned) { ar & fg.count; }
} }

int main() {

    InstanceManager im;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << im;

}
```

Prints

> `22 serialization::archive 12 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 846930886 0 0 7 label b 0 0 24 1681692777 7 label c 18446744073709551607 1804289383 7 label a 42`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the boost serialization using text file. Now I am trying to serialize the instances to binary file but get new problems. I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804174/boost-binary-serialization-doesnt-work-occasionally-the-parsed-data-is-corrupt . I'll appreciate it if you can offer some help.